OOM in spark 3.5.x with bucketing in Apache iceberg
Getting OOM errors on Spark with iceberg. Looks like bucketing leads to unnecessary shuffling and kill the JVM with OOM. The data is evenly distributed no skewness here.
spark.sql(
  """
    |CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rest.db.customers (
    |  customer_id INT,
    |  customer_name STRING,
    |  date DATE,
    |  transaction_details STRING
    |) USING iceberg
    |PARTITIONED BY (bucket(1000, customer_id), days(date))""".stripMargin)

  val customerData = generateCustomerData(1 to 100000) // This generate 100K tuples with 4 columns
  // Convert to DataFrame
  val customerDF = customerData.toDF("customer_id", "customer_name", "date", "transaction_details")
  // Write the data to an Apache Iceberg table
  customerDF
    .write
    .format("iceberg")
    .mode("append")
    .save("rest.db.customers")

